# CheckedListBox , Populating a row of Checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, checkedlistbox

My application is running unstable because I have to many checkboxes in one form. I heard from some source, that I should try to populate the checkboxes in a `CheckedListBox`. But I dont know how i can realize that. Among I wanna show you my solution with `CheckBox`.

Can anyone show me how I can populate this with a `CheckedListBox`?

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxTask; i++)
        {
            Label labelTasks = new Label();
            labelTasks.Text = "A" + i;
            labelTasks.Width = 28;
            labelTasks.Height = 13;
            labelTasks.Location = new Point(boundX_Label, boundY_Label);
            boundX_Label += 26;
            panel.Controls.Add(labelTasks);

            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
            checkBox.Name = String.Format("checkboxTask{0}", i);
            checkBox.GotFocus += checkBox_GotFocus;
            checkBox.LostFocus += checkBox_LostFocus;
            checkBox.Text = "";
            checkBox.Width = 20;
            checkBox.Height = 15;
            checkBox.Location = new Point(boundX_ChkBox, boundY_ChkBox);
            boundX_ChkBox += 26;

            checkBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkBox_CheckedChanged);

            panel.Controls.Add(checkBox);

        }
```

This code will populate a row of checkboxes like showing among. My application have around 200 of this checkbox rows.

[image]

Comment: `CheckedListBox` is just a glorified ListBox.  Add to the Items collection

Comment: So it won't solve the problem?

Comment: I have no idea what (other) problem you might have.  The posts says you dont know how to use a checkedlistbox.  I explained *that*:  `myCLB.Items.Add("A34")`

Comment: But how can I assign a name for every CheckBox in a CheckBoxList? Your example with Add("A34") is the text of a CheckBox, when im not wrong. And I dont need the Text, there should be only Checkboxes without Texts, but to use them later in Eventhandler i want give them a name. Like above with normal Checkbox.

Comment: The screenshot in the question shows you need a text with each checkbox, so it seems a `CheckedListBox` is a good option. You can find `CheckedIndices` or `CheckedItems` or check if an specific item is checked using `GetItemChecked`. If you share more context about your requirement, probably you will receive more effective help.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use a `CheckedListBox` for this, you can add items to
>   CheckedListBox by simply doing- [CheckedListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("A1");
```